# How to copy package.json in Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with copying my `package.json` to Dockerfile context, here is my files tree:

```
src
- apps
-- api
--- Dockerfile
- docker
-- tcp
--- docker-compose.yml
- package.json
```

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.8.0-alpine as develop

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ../package.json .
COPY ../yarn.lock .

RUN yarn install


CMD npm run build api&& node dist/apps/api/main
```

and docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    container_name: api-gateway
    build:
      context: ../../apps/api
      dockerfile: ../../apps/api/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    hostname: api
    env_file:
      - ../../.env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - backend
```

can someone tell me how to copy properly package.json file to resolve below error?

```
 => ERROR [3/5] COPY ../package.json .                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [4/5] COPY ../yarn.lock .                                                                                0.0s
------
 > [3/5] COPY ../package.json .:
------
------
 > [4/5] COPY ../yarn.lock .:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/yarn.lock" not found: not found
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: remove `COPY ../yarn.lock .`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone not help

Comment: move the docker compose file to the top level and then instead of looking for files in the directory above change the paths to be however many levels down so ./package.json

Comment: you cannot from copy above the context. This is not allowed `../`

Answer (score 3):

Move docker-compose.yml to the root of the project

Remove the context since it defaults to the current folder and change the Dockerfile path (or move the Dockerfile too since it is not part of your app source code)

```
build:
  dockerfile: src/apps/api/Dockerfile
```

Update the env file too

Then copy from the direct context. The container should be responsible for its own yarn lock file, IMO, so don't need to copy that. (I've ran into issues where I've forgotten to update the lock file on the host, after modifying package json, so then the build fails with version conflicts when including the lock file)

```
COPY package.json .
```

You should also consider adding a `.dockerignore` for at least `node_modules`